# css align two background images in separate divs

Tags: css, background-image

So I have two dives under each other and I would like to have the 2 background images aligned. The with of both images are the same but the hight is different. (the second image should repeat instelf (ideally have a javascript that would load it while scrolling).

So I was able to align the images but scaling is problem (fixed size right now).

Does anybody knows how to do it?

Here is my code so far

```html
@extends('layouts.application')

@section('styles')

<style type="text/css">

 .bgimage{
  background-image: url('{{ asset('/images/bg/logo.png') }}');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
     background-position: left;
  background-position: left;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
 }

 .image {
  background-image: url('{{ asset('/images/bg/stripe.png') }}');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
     background-position: left;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-position: left;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;


 }

</style>

@endsection

@section('layout-content')

<div class="bgimage" > </div>
<div class="image"> </div>

<!--/End Footer -->

@endsection

@section('scripts')
 

@endsection
```

Thanks allot

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I got the requirement completely, but here is an attempt :

https://jsfiddle.net/wkjys4cu/1/

```css
.outer-container {width: 900px;position: relative;}
.box {
  width: 50%;
  height: 250px; 
  background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_tree.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
}

.box1 {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-position: 50% 60%;
}

.box2 {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  background-size: 50% 75%;
  background-position: 20% 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="outer-container">
    <div class="box box1"></div>
    <div class="box box2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried that but the problem is here that you are using a height expressed in pixels so had some problems when scaling.